# mysql trigger when no match found

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to setup a mysql trigger. So lets assume the table is like this

```
mysql> explain users;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| name       | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| age        | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| purge_date | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

and

```
mysql> explain users_details;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| age   | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

so the trigger i have setup will create a purge_date of NOW on the users table when something is removed from the users_details table. This is fine.

The issue is that sometimes the data for the users_details table comes through incorrectly and then the users update it so then i need to remove the purge_date if they re-insert the data. Now I have made this trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER purge_fix AFTER INSERT ON users_details
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE users
        SET purge_date= '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
        WHERE users.name = NEW.name;
END;
```

Which works fine but in some situations there will not be a link between the users_details table and the users table (it will be created at a later stage) so my question is, as the trigger will fail in some situations (which is 100% fine by me), will I be breaking something having the trigger failing?

Comment: If the update in the trigger finds no rows matching the where clause, it will continue execution without any error, and won't update anything. If the trigger is expected to fail in such a case, you need to signal the error manually in the trigger code, but in this case the whole transaction will fail, the insert too.

Comment: I really don't think "failing sometimes" a good idea for three reasons; it won't help if you're debugging something, developers and dbas can get confused and someday someone that matters may judge your work.

Comment: @kordirko so with the trigger being set "AFTER INSERT", if there is no matching in the the where clause the insert itself will still fail?

Comment: @Leo OK, i guess you are right. the trigger was just such convenient place to do what i'm trying to accomplish. I guess I will have to look elsewhere to get this done. thanks for the advise.

Comment: No, the trigger won't fail, please take a look at this example, it works perfectly fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/986aec/2